# To disclose (termination) or not to disclose?

Tags: job-search, termination

I work at a large organization. After working at this organization for several years our management has announced to me that they will be terminating my contract. I am not leaving the company on very good terms (especially with management), since I have been a disruptive employee (I have my own reasons for this, which I believe are justified to some extent) and spoke my mind a bit more than the average employee working there. I don't believe they have grounds for any serious misconduct other than very openly displaying my dissatisfaction with the way things are run there.

After my notice period ends I will probably be jobless. I will then have to explain to potential employers why I do not work there anymore. Should I disclose that I was terminated? I can imagine this would discourage future employers from hiring me if I am 100% transparent about it. What is the best way of proceeding here?

Comment: To be clear: Where you terminated as in *fired*, or terminated as in *let go or made redundant*? Usually I'd assume "Terminated" means the former, but you mention a notice period which generally only happens with the latter.

Comment: Or terminating meaning not renewing contract.

Comment: Terminated meaning I already had a contract and they are ending it after deciding I am not a good fit as a result of insufficient performance.

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more explicit. Was it a "fixed-term" contract, or an "open-ended" contract?

Comment: it was open-ended

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I explain wrongful termination in an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15262/how-do-i-explain-wrongful-termination-in-an-interview)

Comment: @gnat wrongful termination is different than termination for cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I disclose that I was terminated?

If you are asked why you left your last job (which will almost always be asked), then you should be honest and disclose that you were terminated. You should also have a story to tell about why you were fired, and a way to assure your next employer that it won't happen again.

If you are not asked, there's no need to disclose anything.